# How to include progress bar view inside another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a custom chat bubble inside one layout and a progressbar in another layout . I know how to include a whole layout inside another layout . But i want to include a view i.e progress bar only inside another layout .

**This is my chat bubble layout .**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/message_content_box"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="0dp">

<com.chatbubble.BubbleFrameLayout
android:id="@+id/message_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="18dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
custom:bubbleColor="@color/theme_light"
custom:bubbleCornerRadius="6dp"
custom:bubbleArrowType="standard"
custom:bubbleArrowPosition="right"
custom:bubbleArrowAlign="end"
custom:bubbleArrowWidth="8dp"
custom:bubbleArrowHeight="16dp"
custom:bubbleArrowOffset="-14dp">

<include layout="@layout/message_content"/>

</com.chatbubble.BubbleFrameLayout>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/message_status"
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/message_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/message_status_content_description"
android:src="@drawable/ic_message_success" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**and below is my layout with the progressbar.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/message_file_controls"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/message_file_controls1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/file_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:text="IMG-55122.jpg (1.5M)"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:textScaleX="0.5" />

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/file_progress"
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
android:layout_width="160dp"
android:layout_height="3dip"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/file_status"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example"
android:max="100"
android:maxWidth="220dp"
android:progress="0"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/message_ft_progress_bar" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/file_status"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/file_title"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:text="0%"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate the layout and add the view you want, something like this.

```
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOURXMLLAYOUT, null, false);
   ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.file_progress);
   YourLayout.addView(pb);
```

But if i were in your skin i will just do:

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(this);
YourLayout.addView(pb);
```

Hppe this helps.